# How do I find bias and variance of estimators of a binomial distribution?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, expected-value, estimators

A product-lot arrives in two containers with respectively 300 and 700 units in each container. We examine 30 units in the first container and find that 1 of them is defective. We check 70 units in the other containter and find that 2 of them is defective. The following estimators for the defect rate  are proposed:

p1 = (X1 + X2)/100

p2 = (3X1 + 7X2)/580

p3 = X1/30

p4 = X2/70

What is the distribution of X1 and X2, and what expectation and variance do they have?

How do I find the expectation of each of the estimators?

Answer (score 1):

Given $p$, (or if it is assumed fixed), both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are binomial RVs, with $n_1=30,n_2=70$ respectively. So, the expectations are $n_1p$ and $n_2p$, while variances are $n_1p(1-p)$ and $n_2p(1-p)$. The expectations for estimators can be obtained via *linearity of expectation* since all are in $aX_1+bX_2$ form, and you know the means of $X_i$; i.e. $E[aX_1+bX_2]=aE[X_1]+bE[X_2]$.